# Is there a way to make sure a Boost.Test test can fail when it ought to?

Tags: c++, testing, boost, boost-test

I recently discovered a bug in one of my tests - it would always pass even when it should have failed.  Is there a way to use the Boost.Test framework to require that a test fails when given inputs for which it is expected to fail?  (I don't want to write two separate tests because the goal is to test the test itself.)  Here's what I have in mind:

```
void test_funct(double arg_a, double arg_b) {
  BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(arg_a, 1.0, 0.1);
  BOOST_CHECK_CLOSE(arg_b, 1.0, 0.1);
}  

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test) {  
  test_funct(1.0, 1.0);  // this should be required to have no failures
  test_funct(1.0, 2.0);  // this should be required to have at least one failure
}
```

I did find a couple of things that aren't exactly what I want.  There's the [expected_failures decorator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/testing_tools/expected_failures.html) but it doesn't actually *require* an error.
There's also [this old post](https://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2006/06/19990.php) on the boost mailing list which proposes

```
BOOST_CHECK_PREDICATE( not( check_is_close ), (a)(b)(percent_tolerance(t)) );
```

but it would require *every* `check_is_close` to fail rather than just requiring at least one to fail.  (Plus that code doesn't compile for me.)

Comment: This question seems to speak to a misunderstanding of how unit tests work. If you expect a failure on given inputs and don't get it, that means your code is broken. Fix your code to give you the desired behavior.

Comment: @sweenish OP wants to express that `test_func` - which contains more than one assertion - should  fail at least one of them. There is no "meta-assertion" which means, IMO, the answer is that it cannot be done. Of course, OP can restructure their tests to not require the meta-assertion